# Poodle and Websphere ESB / Process Server trying to call an external TLS service

Tags: java, ssl, websphere

I had the following error when calling a service that requests at least TLS (no SSL3 for you Poodle!).

> com.ibm.websphere.sca.ServiceUnavailableException: Could not obtain a connection to the destination or Exception was happened on the connection. Failed to process the request. Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0
>       at com.ibm.ws.http.imprt.handler.HTTPImportService.sendHTTPRequest(HTTPImportService.java:254)
>       at com.ibm.ws.http.imprt.handler.HTTPImportHandler.processMessage(HTTPImportHandler.java:261)
>       at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.message.impl.MessageDispatcherImpl.processMessageWithPCI(MessageDispatcherImpl.java:785)
>       at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.message.impl.MessageDispatcherImpl.processMessage(MessageDispatcherImpl.java:1626)
>       at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.message.impl.ManagedMessageImpl.process(ManagedMessageImpl.java:999)
>       at com.ibm.ws.sca.uow.handler.UOWNativeWASStrategyImpl.transactionImportExport(UOWNativeWASStrategyImpl.java:455)
>       at com.ibm.ws.sca.uow.handler.JoinUOWNativeHandler.processMessage(JoinUOWNativeHandler.java:168)
>       at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.message.impl.MessageDispatcherImpl.processMessageWithPCI(MessageDispatcherImpl.java:785)
>       at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.message.impl.MessageDispatcherImpl.processMessage(MessageDispatcherImpl.java:1626)
>       at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.message.impl.ManagedMessageImpl.process(ManagedMessageImpl.java:990)
>       at com.ibm.ws.sibx.mediation.flowaction.impl.sca.SCAInvocationAction.invokeSync(SCAInvocationAction.java:554)
>       at com.ibm.ws.sibx.mediation.flowaction.impl.sca.RetryControl.invokeByStyle(RetryControl.java:379)
>       at com.ibm.ws.sibx.mediation.flowaction.impl.sca.RetryControl.invokeWithRetry(RetryControl.java:253)
>       at com.ibm.ws.sibx.mediation.flowaction.impl.sca.ServiceInvocation.complete(ServiceInvocation.java:127)
>       at com.ibm.ws.sibx.mediation.flowaction.impl.sca.FlowActionFactoryImpl.create(FlowActionFactoryImpl.java:750)
>       at com.ibm.ws.sibx.mediation.primitives.serviceinvoke.ServiceInvokeMediation.invokeFlowAction(ServiceInvokeMediation.java:651)
>       at com.ibm.ws.sibx.mediation.primitives.serviceinvoke.ServiceInvokeMediation.mediate(ServiceInvokeMediation.java:564)
>       at com.ibm.ws.sibx.scax.mediation.engine.JavaMediationPrimitive.performInvocation(JavaMediationPrimitive.java:741)
>       at com.ibm.ws.sibx.scax.mediation.engine.JavaMediationPrimitive.performInvocationWithCatch(JavaMediationPrimitive.java:577)
>       at com.ibm.ws.sibx.scax.mediation.engine.JavaMediationPrimitive.invoke(JavaMediationPrimitive.java:397)
>       at com.ibm.ws.sibx.scax.mediation.engine.SIBXJavaMediationPrimitive.invoke(SIBXJavaMediationPrimitive.java:108)
>       at com.ibm.ws.sibx.scax.mediation.engine.MediationPrimitive.invokeConnections(MediationPrimitive.java:344)
>       at com.ibm.ws.sibx.scax.mediation.engine.JavaMediationPrimitive.fireOutputTerminals(JavaMediationPrimitive.java:843)
>       at com.ibm.ws.sibx.scax.mediation.engine.JavaMediationPrimitive.performInvocation(JavaMediationPrimitive.java:763)
>       at com.ibm.ws.sibx.scax.mediation.engine.JavaMediationPrimitive.performInvocationWithCatch(JavaMediationPrimitive.java:577)
>       at com.ibm.ws.sibx.scax.mediation.engine.JavaMediationPrimitive.invoke(JavaMediationPrimitive.java:397)
>       at com.ibm.ws.sibx.scax.mediation.engine.MediationPrimitive.invokeConnections(MediationPrimitive.java:344)
>       at com.ibm.ws.sibx.scax.mediation.engine.JavaMediationPrimitive.fireOutputTerminals(JavaMediationPrimitive.java:843)
>       at com.ibm.ws.sibx.scax.mediation.engine.JavaMediationPrimitive.performInvocation(JavaMediationPrimitive.java:763)
>       at com.ibm.ws.sibx.scax.mediation.engine.JavaMediationPrimitive.performInvocationWithCatch(JavaMediationPrimitive.java:577)
>       at com.ibm.ws.sibx.scax.mediation.engine.JavaMediationPrimitive.invoke(JavaMediationPrimitive.java:397)
>       at com.ibm.ws.sibx.scax.mediation.engine.MediationPrimitive.invokeConnections(MediationPrimitive.java:344)
>       at com.ibm.ws.sibx.scax.mediation.engine.Input.invoke(Input.java:245)

The config was Websphere 8.0.0.7 with Websphere Process Server 8.0.1.2 and I was calling to an HTTP service using an HTTP import through https, the WAS was already using a SSL configuration with TLS (tried several options, all same error) and the ssl.client.props file is already following the IBM recommendations (tried several combinations).

Then we moved to FIPS with transitional support but another issue appeared

> com.ibm.websphere.sca.ServiceUnavailableException: Could not obtain a
>   connection to the destination or Exception was happened on the
>   connection. Failed to process the request. SSL protocol cannot be
>   enabled in FIPS/SP800_131/suiteb mode
>       at com.ibm.ws.http.imprt.handler.HTTPImportService.sendHTTPRequest(HTTPImportService.java:254)
>       at com.ibm.ws.http.imprt.handler.HTTPImportHandler.processMessage(HTTPImportHandler.java:261)
>       at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.message.impl.MessageDispatcherImpl.processMessageWithPCI(MessageDispatcherImpl.java:785)
>       at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.message.impl.MessageDispatcherImpl.processMessage(MessageDispatcherImpl.java:1626)
>       at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.message.impl.ManagedMessageImpl.process(ManagedMessageImpl.java:999)
>       at com.ibm.ws.sca.uow.handler.UOWNativeWASStrategyImpl.transactionImportExport(UOWNativeWASStrategyImpl.java:455)
>       at com.ibm.ws.sca.uow.handler.JoinUOWNativeHandler.processMessage(JoinUOWNativeHandler.java:168)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was within the HTTP import internal component (was using SSL as a hardcoded configuration) so I wrote my own HTTP client in a custom Java and called it a day. No fix pack at that moment.